# how to include Leaflet (for R)-output into RMarkdown presentation?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown

According to the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/), Leaflet output created with the "leaflet" package for R can be included into RMarkdown.

This works when the RMarkdown output is html:

````
---
title: "Rmarkdown HTML including Leaflet"
output: html_document
---

Show "Leaflet for R" within html: works.

```{r}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles %>% # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  setView(lng = 5.0, lat = 51.0, zoom = 6)
```
````

But fails when the RMarkdown output is a presentation:

````
---
title: "Rmarkdown Presentation including Leaflet"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation
---

Show "Leaflet for R" within Rmarkdown presentation: fails.

```{r}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles %>% # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  setView(lng = 5.0, lat = 51.0, zoom = 6)
```
````

My objective is to create a presentation that includes the Leaflet output. How to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119488/how-to-embed-a-leaflet-map-into-a-reveal-js-presentation

Comment: I found this post using search before posting my question, but it didn't help me. 
If possible, i would like to use the RMarkdown/R leaflet package for creating my presentation, instead of controlling the leaflet Javascript library from reveal.js directly as i don't know Javascript/css.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real solution, but a workaround: when changing from a revealjs presentation type to ioslides, the Leaflet output is shown in the presentation. The layout and interactivity do not work flawless though.

````
---
title: "Rmarkdown Presentation including Leaflet"
author: "UVH"
date: "March 14, 2016"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation
---

Show "Leaflet for R" within Rmarkdown "ioslides" presentation: works, but not flawless.

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles %>% # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  setView(lng = 5.0, lat = 51.0, zoom = 6)
```
````

As I prefer using revealjs over ioslides, I hope someone can provide a better solution that does work with revealjs.

Comment: and a "Slidy" type of presentation (output: slidy_presentation) works best.
Still, these presentation types are less 'smooth' than "reveal.js".